# How to do hide/show functionality using buttons in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Now I currently developing a mobile musical app using ionic3 framework

In my project there is a two buttons

One is **`about`** button and another is an **`music`** button

**These two buttons are located in same div**. 
**`about`** button is in **right side** and **`music`** button is in **left side**

So whenever user click the **`about`** button, I need to show details about artist.if users click **`music`** button,then I need to show songs list to users

I have a details about artist and songs list...but I don't know how to display it..can any one help me?

Comment: Are these artist details and songs list different pages in your mobile app or do you have to show them in the same page?

Comment: i need show in same page @SakshamGupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this in your template.html

```
<div>
  <button ion-button (click)="onAboutClick()">About</button>
  <button ion-button (click)="onMusicClick()">Music</button>
<div>

<div *ngIf="isAboutAvailable">
  // about content
</div>

<div *ngIf="isMusicAvailable">
  // music content
</div>
```

In your component

```
public onAboutClick(): void {
   this.isAboutAvailable = !this.isAboutAvailable;
   this.isMusicAvailable = false;
}

public onAboutClick(): void {
   this.isAboutAvailable = false;
   this.isMusicAvailable = !this.isMusicAvailable;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should also toggle the other flag on click of the buttons or else both the divs will show at the same time.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks its working well @AnuradhaGunasekara